# Python SimpleCookie and JSON Value

Tags: python, python-3.x, cookies, httpcookie

I've run into some problems using Python's `SimpleCookie` when using a JSON string as a value.

```
In [1]: from http.cookies import SimpleCookie

In [2]: cookie = SimpleCookie('x=1; json={"myVal":1}; y=2')

In [3]: cookie.keys()
Out[3]: dict_keys(['x'])

In [4]: cookie = SimpleCookie('x=1; y=2')

In [5]: cookie.keys()
Out[5]: dict_keys(['y', 'x'])
```

Not only the JSON string is missing, but every other value coming afterwards as well. I'm wondering now if this is a Python-related bug as the characters should all be fine to be used in a cookie?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you're trying to use an object as the value, not a JSON string representation of that object. You need to escape the JSON string within your argument string, as follows:

```
>>> from http.cookies import SimpleCookie
>>> cookie = SimpleCookie(r'x=1; json="{\"myVal\":1}"; y=2')
                        # ^ note raw string    ^ and single backslashes
>>> cookie.keys()
dict_keys(['json', 'x', 'y'])
```

It does seem odd that a malformed string is quietly consumed as far as it can go and the rest is ditched, though; I'd expect a `ValueError` or something for your input. [The parser](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/http/cookies.py#l563) just stops and returns the result so far when it's run out of things that match the regex.

---

Given [Marius's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38206698/3001761), which seemed to work on 3.3.2 but doesn't work in 3.5.2 (and, to me, doesn't look like it should work *anywhere*; an implicit JSON package import?!) I went searching for when it changed. Using this script:

```
from http.cookies import SimpleCookie
import json
from sys import version

print(version)

cookie1 = SimpleCookie('x=1; json=json.dumps({"myVal":1}); y=2')
print('Marius  ', cookie1.keys(), repr(cookie1.get('json')), sep='\t')

cookie2 = SimpleCookie(r'x=1; json="{\"myVal\":1}"; y=2')
print('Jonathan', cookie2.keys(), repr(cookie2.get('json')), sep='\t')

cookie3 = SimpleCookie('x=1; json={"myVal":1}; y=2')
print('Bernhard', cookie3.keys(), repr(cookie3.get('json')), sep='\t')
```

and `pyenv` on Mac OS X gives the following results for 3.3:

```
3.3.0 (default, Jul  7 2016, 10:47:41)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72)]
Marius      dict_keys(['x', 'y', 'json'])   <Morsel: json='json.dumps({'>
Jonathan    dict_keys(['x', 'y', 'json'])   <Morsel: json='{"myVal":1}'>
Bernhard    dict_keys(['x', 'y', 'json'])   <Morsel: json='{'>

3.3.1 (default, Jul  7 2016, 10:53:06)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72)]
Marius      dict_keys(['json', 'x', 'y'])   <Morsel: json='json.dumps({'>
Jonathan    dict_keys(['json', 'x', 'y'])   <Morsel: json='{"myVal":1}'>
Bernhard    dict_keys(['json', 'x', 'y'])   <Morsel: json='{'>

3.3.2 (default, Jul  6 2016, 22:02:23)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72)]
Marius      dict_keys(['json', 'y', 'x'])   <Morsel: json='json.dumps({'>
Jonathan    dict_keys(['json', 'y', 'x'])   <Morsel: json='{"myVal":1}'>
Bernhard    dict_keys(['json', 'y', 'x'])   <Morsel: json='{'>

# ...loses 'json'

3.3.3 (default, Jul  7 2016, 10:57:02)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72)]
Marius      dict_keys(['x', 'y'])   None
Jonathan    dict_keys(['x', 'y', 'json'])   <Morsel: json='{"myVal":1}'>
Bernhard    dict_keys(['x', 'y'])   None

3.3.4 (default, Jul  7 2016, 10:59:21)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72)]
Marius      dict_keys(['y', 'x'])   None
Jonathan    dict_keys(['y', 'x', 'json'])   <Morsel: json='{"myVal":1}'>
Bernhard    dict_keys(['y', 'x'])   None

3.3.5 (default, Jul  7 2016, 11:01:45)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72)]
Marius      dict_keys(['y', 'x'])   None
Jonathan    dict_keys(['json', 'y', 'x'])   <Morsel: json='{"myVal":1}'>
Bernhard    dict_keys(['y', 'x'])   None

# ...and now 'y'!

3.3.6 (default, Jul  7 2016, 11:03:40)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72)]
Marius      dict_keys(['x'])    None
Jonathan    dict_keys(['json', 'x', 'y'])   <Morsel: json='{"myVal":1}'>
Bernhard    dict_keys(['x'])    None
```

From there it seems to be stable:

```
3.4.4 (default, Jul  7 2016, 11:13:43)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72)]
Marius      dict_keys(['x'])    None
Jonathan    dict_keys(['json', 'y', 'x'])   <Morsel: json='{"myVal":1}'>
Bernhard    dict_keys(['x'])    None

3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 26 2016, 10:47:25)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]
Marius      dict_keys(['x'])    None
Jonathan    dict_keys(['x', 'json', 'y'])   <Morsel: json="{\"myVal\":1}">
Bernhard    dict_keys(['x'])    None
```

The version from 3.3.6 onwards was apparently a security fix; see [this bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue25228). This was also applied in 3.2.6, so:

```
3.2.4 (default, Jul  7 2016, 11:05:33)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72)]
Marius      dict_keys(['y', 'x', 'json'])   <Morsel: json='json.dumps({'>
Jonathan    dict_keys(['y', 'x', 'json'])   <Morsel: json='{"myVal":1}'>
Bernhard    dict_keys(['y', 'x', 'json'])   <Morsel: json='{'>

3.2.5 (default, Jul  7 2016, 11:07:15)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72)]
Marius      dict_keys(['y', 'x', 'json'])   <Morsel: json='json.dumps({'>
Jonathan    dict_keys(['y', 'x', 'json'])   <Morsel: json='{"myVal":1}'>
Bernhard    dict_keys(['y', 'x', 'json'])   <Morsel: json='{'>

# ...loses 'y'?!

3.2.6 (default, Jul  7 2016, 11:09:00)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72)]
Marius      dict_keys(['x', 'json'])    <Morsel: json='json.dumps({'>
Jonathan    dict_keys(['y', 'x', 'json'])   <Morsel: json='{"myVal":1}'>
Bernhard    dict_keys(['x', 'json'])    <Morsel: json='{'>
```

This behaviour is *different* to 3.3.6 with the same bugfix! In fact, it sets the value of `json` in the cookie to `'{'`, discarding the rest of that value and `y`.

I conclude that:

1. my version is more widely applicable;
2. Marius's version won't actually help the OP, as it has the same keys as their original version; and
3. something weird was happening with this functionality in 3.2 and 3.3!

Comment: this answer helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This includes `'json'` as a key in Python 3.3.2 and earlier:

```
>>> import json
>>> from http.cookies import SimpleCookie
>>> cookie = SimpleCookie('x=1; json=json.dumps({"myVal":1}); y=2')
>>> cookie.keys()
dict_keys(['y', 'x', 'json'])
```

However, the value may not be as expected:

```
>>> print(cookie)
Set-Cookie: json=json.dumps({
Set-Cookie: x=1
Set-Cookie: y=2
```

Comment: You are right : I should have added the import json line. I have tested this and the output is correct.

Comment: I use Python 3.3.2 version

Comment: http://labs.codecademy.com/DX3H#:workspace <- Proof that this code works for some versions of Python

Comment: Well I stand thoroughly corrected, having had to install `pyenv` to get a 3.3.2 interpreter. I apologise, and will now have to go and find out when and why that changed (and why the docs don't seem to mention it).

Comment: And now, bizarrely, it seems that 3.3.5 outputs `x`and `y` but skips `json`, and 3.3.6 just gives `x`.

Comment: I have updated my answer for the whole 3.3 line - your version works up to 3.3.2, then there's a third kind of behaviour from 3.3.3-3.3.5, then at 3.3.6 I see the same as 3.4 and 3.5. Weird.